# How to call External Javascript Firestore function in a Typescript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using Node.js to upload a Typescript file(**index.ts**) with Cloud functions. I now have a Firestore trigger written in external JavaScript file(**notifyNewMessage.js**), which I would like to somehow declare in the Typescript file.

Both files are in the same directory:

[image]

---

index.ts:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

//declare javascript file here???

export const cloudFunction= functions
  .firestore.document(`Users/{user_id}`).onWrite(async (change, _context) => {

   //Function code....

}
```

---

notifyNewMessage.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.firestore{
   //Cloud function I want to declare in index.ts
}
```

It would be great if anyone can provide a way for me to do this, or point me in a direction where I can learn how, as Typescript and JavaScript are not my strong points :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to import an exported function from the js file. Wouldn't it be something simple as one of the following:

```
import notifyNewMessage from "./notifyNewMessage";
```

OR

```
import { notifyNewMessage } from "./notifyNewMessage";
```